# What system do DGT boards use?

Tags: software, chessboards

DGT boards allow it to be connected with a computer, and thus sending it the moves. WHat algorithm does it use to verify the moves pieces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This page](https://www.chessprogramming.org/DGT_Board) contains a lot of information about DGT boards, including the patent, detailed description of technologies and algorithms used. Many additional references are provided, too. It is definitely an interesting read!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: True, but I would not pretend to grasp half of the concepts/technologies in play and so could not hope to explain it nearly as well as the page does. Perhaps someone else can.

Answer (score 3):

The board does not verify the moves played at all. It does not even recognize the concept of a "move" - it just tells you where every piece is when you ask for it.